# Print the solution to maximum sum of non-consecutive elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to display the elements in an array that sum up to a max number and no two elements are consecutive(adjacent).

I figured out how to calculate the max sum by maintaining an **inclusive** and **exclusive** sum of the array elements. Is there any optimized way to capture all the elements that constitute the max sum and display it in reverse order

Code :

```
int i_sum = tickets[0];
int e_sum = 0;
int new_sum = 0
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
   new_sum = (i_sum > e_sum) ? i_sum : e_sum;
   i_sum = e_sum + tickets[i];
   e_sum = new_sum;
 }
 (i_sum >= e_sum) ? std::cout << "incl " << i_sum : std::cout << "excl " << e_sum;
```

For example :

n = 8

array = [ 100 , -3 , 200 , 50 , 400 , -7 , 20 , 80 ]

**max sum = 780**

**output : 
80,400,200,100**

And if both the inclusive and exclusive sum is alike the output would be the one with the greater element set.

Case :

n = 4

array = [4 , 5 , 4, 3]

**max sum = 8**

**output : 4, 4**

Should I maintain two different arrays to hold all the possible values, or insert them one at a time on each pass?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could maintain two arrays and copy and swap them at each step. However, that is not optimal. It will make your algorithm **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

```
  std::vector<int> incl, excl;
  if (tickets[0] > 0)
    incl.push_back(tickets[0]);

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    std::vector<int> temp;
    if (i_sum > e_sum) {
      new_sum = i_sum;
    } else {
      new_sum = e_sum;
      temp = excl;
   }
   i_sum = e_sum + tickets[i];
   e_sum = new_sum;
   excl.push_back(tickets[i]);
   std::swap(incl, excl);
   if (temp.size())
     excl = temp;
  }
```

`incl` or `excl` will contain your solution depending whichever is larger.

I've made a small optimization using `std::swap` to use move semantics that avoids copies but when `e_sum > i_sum`, we can't avoid copying `temp` to `excl`.

Instead, formulating the same problem using dynamic programming, you can accomplish this in **O(n)**. The idea is similar. Either you include the current element and add to the solution to max sum of second previous element or you exclude the current element to have the solution for the previous element. Code as follows:

```
  vector <int> dp(n);
  vector <int> parent(n, 0);
  if (tickets[0] > 0) {
    dp[0] = tickets[0];
    parent[0] = tickets[0];
  }
  if (tickets[1] > 0) {
    dp[1] = tickets[1];
    parent[1] = tickets[1];
  }
  for (int i = 2; i < n ; i++) {
    if (dp[i-1] > tickets[i] + dp[i-2]) {
      dp[i] = dp[i-1];
    } else {
      dp[i] = tickets[i] + dp[i-2];
      parent[i] = tickets[i];
    }
  }
  cout << "Max sum: " << dp[n-1] << endl;

  for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0;) {
    if (parent[i]) {
      cout << parent[i] << ' ';
      i = i - 2;
    } else {
      i--;
    }
  }
```

`parent` vector can be utilized to trace back the steps taken for the dynamic programming solution.

As a side note, the solution mentioned in your question is slightly incorrect. If the first element is negative, you'd get an unoptimal result.

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you. On your note, correct me if I'm wrong, I see you did the same thing to dodge any negative number.

Comment: The bug is the first line of your code. `int i_sum = tickets[0];`. You include it without checking for a negative. For the rest, my algorithm is the same as yours.